# Kotlin Coroutines validate running on same Dispatcher

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I have a custom Scope that is using a single thread as it's Dispatcher.

```
private val jsDispatcher = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()
private val jsScope = CoroutineScope(jsDispatcher + SupervisorJob() + CoroutineName("JS-Thread"))
```

Let's assume I have a code block that uses the above scope to launch a new coroutine and call multiple suspend methods

```
jsScope.launch {
    sampleMethod()
    sampleMethod2()
    sampleMethod3()
}
```

I need to validate and throw an exception if one of the above sample methods is not running on the above JS thread

```
private suspend fun sampleMethod() = coroutineScope {
    //Implement me
    validateThread()
}
```

How can this be enforced?

Comment: `withContext(jsDispatcher)`?

Comment: @Nicolas Nope, this is not what I am looking for, if I switch context then no need to validate :)

Comment: You can check the current thread name with `Thread.currentThread().name`, however it will have a name like `pool-2-thread-1` which can hardly be validated. There's a way to customize the names, but first, am I understanding your question correctly? Why not `withContext`, what do you want to do if the thread is wrong?

Comment: @Nicolas I have edited the question to add more clarification. Once i get to method sampleMethod I don't want to switch context since I already am on it. But just want to validate that no one else will from another scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I took a look at the `withContext()` implementation and the answer to my question was right there.

Taken from the `withContext()` implementation, this is how to check if current coroutine context is on same dispatcher as other context/scope

```
if (newContext[ContinuationInterceptor] === oldContext[ContinuationInterceptor]) {
    // same dispatcher
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the current thread name in your method:

```
private suspend fun sampleMethod() = coroutineScope {
    assert(Thread.currentThread().name == "js-thread")  // Doesn't work!
}
```

However, `newSingleThreadExecutor` uses `DefaultThreadFactory` which produces thread names like `pool-N-thread-M` which cannot really be validated because you don't know M or N. I see two solutions here:

1. Take advantage of the fact that you have a single thread and change its name as soon as you create the executor:

   ```
   runBlocking {
       jsScope.launch {
           Thread.currentThread().name = "js-thread"
       }
   }
   ```
2. Pass a custom thread factory: `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(MyThreadFactory("js-thread"))`

   ```
   private class MyThreadFactory(private val name: String) : ThreadFactory {

       private val group: ThreadGroup
       private val threadNumber = AtomicInteger(1)

       init {
           val s = System.getSecurityManager()
           group = if (s != null) {
               s.threadGroup
           } else {
               Thread.currentThread().threadGroup
           }
       }

       override fun newThread(r: Runnable): Thread {
           val t = Thread(group, r, "$name-${threadNumber.getAndIncrement()}", 0)
           if (t.isDaemon) {
               t.isDaemon = false
           }
           if (t.priority != Thread.NORM_PRIORITY) {
               t.priority = Thread.NORM_PRIORITY
           }
           return t
       }
   }
   ```

   Code was adapted from [`DefaultThreadFactory`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/6bab0f539fba8fb441697846347597b4a0ade428/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/Executors.java#L612). Guava and apache-commons also provide utility methods to do the same. This has the advantage that it works for any thread pool, not just single-threaded.